# "What you", "that you", "without you" pronunciations using a "ch" between the words

Tags: pronunciation, connected-speech, assimilation-linguistics

I've been trying to learn more about a common English pronunciation oddity. I've been trying to find the right combination of words to google for the last half hour, but I'm at a total loss. Also, I figure this question has been asked on this stack before, but I can't seem to find it.

The question centers on certain words used in front of "you." It's common for people to say the following:

> ***what you*** => pronounced "what-chyou" or "what-cha" or "what-chya"
>
> ***that you*** => pronounced "that-chyou" or "that-choo"
>
> ***without you*** => pronounced "with-out-chyou" or "with-out-choo"

There are many examples of this in popular music. For example, you can hear the alternate pronunciation clearly in U2's "With or Without You." Also, the Beastie Boys have a famous song called "Whatcha Want." And there was a famous catch-phrase from the 1980's sitcom "Different Strokes": *"Whatchyou talkin about, Willis!"*

What is this pronunciation phenomenon called, and where does it come from? Are there particular rules for its usage?

Comment: It seems odd that there would be a specific name for the regional pronunciation of this particular combination of sounds.  How is this unique from, say, the stereotypical New Yorker pronunciation of "What do you ..." as "Waddaya ..."?

Comment: Is it even regional? U2 is from Ireland, Beastie Boys are from NYC. Countless hip hop groups have titles with  "whatcha" in it, and I assume they're from all over the US. It seems almost like a generic kind of slang to me, but I don't really know.

Comment: I think this type of consonant change is an example of palatalization, but I am not a linguist.  You might find this answer interesting: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111207/t-pronounced-as-ch

Comment: Palatalization: https://www.alphadictionary.com/blog/?p=872

Comment: Both describe a long _u_ sound modifying the preceding consonant (particularly when the _u_ has an "intruding y"), and specifically modifying `t -> ch.`  That pretty much captures what you're observing, but you're correct that it isn't specifically limited to your case (which is why I posted a comment, not an answer :-) )

Comment: I agree, it definitely seems like "palatalization." But additionally, I'm wondering if "whatcha" has always connoted informality -- or if that's just a modern usage.

Comment: Related ELU question: [Are what-cha and arent-cha examples of elision?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199490)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "don't you" pronounced "dontcha"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/246241/why-is-dont-you-pronounced-dontcha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version: In fast speech, **T** plus **Y** tends to merge to **TSH**, spelled **CH**, because of where they are pronounced in the mouth.

---

Long version: As Adam hinted, this is really a [linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) question. Sumelic linked to [a pretty comprehensive answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199490/are-what-cha-and-arent-cha-examples-of-elision), but I'll give it another shot.

Here is a [broad IPA transcription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_transcription#Narrow_versus_broad_transcription) of one phrase in American English before and after the change:

> /wʌt**j**u/ *what you* → /wʌt**ʃ**u/ *whatchu*

When you compare them, you can see that although they sound quite different to the ear, only one segment changes: /**j**/ becomes /**ʃ**/.

That first sound is a [palatal glide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_approximant) ("**yuh**") and the second is a [palato-alveolar fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_palato-alveolar_sibilant) ("**shh**"). If you try to make both sounds you'll notice how little your tongue changes position between them.

We notice that in the formal description, two features changed: "palatal" became "palato-alveolar" and "glide" became "fricative".

There are several reasons why features can change, but it's always worth checking if anything in the area could trigger [assimilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(phonology)), the "sharing" of features.

Here, the changing sound is preceded by /t/, an [alveolar stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_dental_and_alveolar_stops#Alveolar). The "alveolar" is why "palatal" shifted to "palato-alveolar". And a fricative is between a glide and a stop in terms of obstruction of airflow. The stop /t/ "pulled" the glide /j/ halfway, ending up at the fricative /ʃ/. **Result: /tʃ/**, pronounced "ch".

---

This assimilation happens easily in quick speech. It's a very natural change and I would not expect it to be bound to one region.

At least, not for phonetic reasons. For [sociolinguistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociolinguistics) reasons, it might have more stigma or cultural currency in different places among different people. I don't believe, however, there is really any group that avoids it. The answer sumelic linked to includes a clip of the Queen using it.

**But *writing* this change by spelling it with a "ch" is very informal.** That spelling is sometimes used as a hint that the speaker is overly casual, not careful in their speech, not educated, or not high-class, even though (again) even the Queen uses it!

---

Incidentally, despite the uncited sentence that closes the introduction to the Wikipedia article on [palatalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(sound_change)), this is a case of [affrication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affricate_consonant). I say that because the sound involved in the change is already palatal before the changes takes place. In fact, it becomes *less* palatal. But it does go from being a glide to a fricative. The resulting combination of a stop /t/ plus a fricative /ʃ/ is an affricate.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was looking for confirmation that all types of people from all parts of the world use palatalization.

Comment: @Ringo You're welcome. But to reiterate, I'd consider "palatalization" a misnomer here.

Comment: affrication, i see! As to why people do this, it seems to me that it might improve the separation of words and make the speaker easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain registers or dialects where the pronunciation, as you posted it, is customary. For example, in African American vernacular. It is also common in informal speech around the San Francisco Bay area that I have noticed. I am not sure about other areas around the U.S.