# Why is "don't you" pronounced "dontcha"?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, phonology, assimilation-linguistics

When I watch movies sometimes I feel the pronunciation for **don't** is not /dəʊnt/ or /doʊnt/, instead it's something similar to **/doʊntʃ/**. For instance here:
Don't you see

I wonder is this something specific to American accent?

Comment: Example from pop culture: https://youtu.be/YNSxNsr4wmA?t=64

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## ;

In General American English, *don't* is pronounced /doʊnt/ while in Southern Standard British English, it's pronounced /dəʊnt/.

In *don't you*, the /t/ of *don't* and /j/ of *you* coalesce to /tʃ/. The process is called [**assimilation**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/248446/106592).

[Assimilation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/270790/106592) makes nearby sounds more similar to each other. The kind of assimilation in *don't you* is called [**coalescent assimilation**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/271401/106592).

When /j/ comes right after /t/, there's a tendency to assimilate them to /t͡ʃ/. The /t/ is normally articulated at the ridge right behind the top teeth (alveolar ridge), but when it comes before a /j/ (which is articulated further back in the mouth—at the hard palate), it's usually pronounced /t͡ʃ/. What happens here is that the /t/ is articulated further back in the mouth in anticipation of the following /j/, so it becomes /t͡ʃ/ i.e. they coalesce to /t͡ʃ/.

The following sounds often coalesce:

- /t/ and /j/ coalesce to /t͡ʃ/ (as in *posthumous*)
- /d/ and /j/ coalesce to /d͡ʒ/ (as in *e**du**cation*)
- /s/ and /j/ coalesce to /ʃ/ (*ble**ss y**ou* is sometimes pronounced *bleshoo*)
- /z/ and /j/ coalesce to /ʒ/ (as in *vi**sio**n*)

You might have noticed that in informal situations (mostly in chatting platforms), most people write contractions such as *dontcha, whatcha, gotcha* etc. These are the phonetic spellings of the assimilated forms.

- dontcha → don't + you
- whatcha → what + you
- gotcha → got + you
- betcha → bet + you

Similarly, 'did you' is often pronounced as /dɪdʒjuː/ because /d/ and /j/ assimilate to /d͡ʒ/.

> I wonder is this something specific to American accent?

No. It's not restricted to American English.

Comment: You can find more information on this specific process if you search for *yod-coalescence*, and you'll find it under *palatalization* as well.

Answer (score 5):

You are hearing the merging of the /t/ with the /j/ (or "y") of you.

If spoken as separate words you would hear.

> don't. you. = /dəʊnt/ /ju:/

But normally these are run together and blend to form something like

> don'tyou = /dəʊntʃu:/ or even "dontcha" (similar to "gonna" or "wanna")

You can hear the same with other words ending in "t",  "I want you to" can become "Iwanchuta" when spoken quickly.