# What is the correct pronunciation of "don't you"?

Tags: pronunciation, silent-letter, connected-speech, assimilation-linguistics

I don't understand what's the standard pronunciation of words ending in ***t*** followed by ***you***, including "*don't you*", "*want you*" etc. Even when hearing the same person talking for some time, their pronunciation seems to vary between:

- don't you (t pronounced [/t/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_dental_and_alveolar_plosives))
- don'you (silent t)
- don'tch you (t becomes [**/tʃ/**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_postalveolar_affricate))

Why does each variation occur and which one would be the correct pronunciation?

Comment: I am unsure about the first and third, but second one is very unusual. Never heard it without a 't'.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh - The second variant, where the /t/ turns into a silent glottal stop or is dropped altogether, is incredibly common in the northeastern United States. It's certainly the way I say this phrase as a native speaker.

Comment: In most such contexts, the standard "eye dialect" representation is [***dontcha***](https://www.yourdictionary.com/dontcha) But whether the final vowel/diphthong is reduced to a schwa or not depends as much on the *context* as on the particular speaker.

Comment: You might want to read [this article by Quick & Dirty Tips](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/pronouncing-T)

Comment: The second is very common in singing pop songs. Sing “don’t you, forget about me” and hear how oddly it scans if you sound the “t”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and foremost, there's no 'correct' or 'incorrect' pronunciation. Pronunciation of a particular word varies from speaker to speaker or accent to accent.

All the pronunciations you've given are correct and native speakers will understand what you mean.

- first case: the t is pronounced a clear t, [t]: no [assimilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(phonology)), [glottalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-glottalization) or [t-deletion](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/icphs-proceedings/ICPhS2003/papers/p15_1835.pdf) (t-dropping). (It's somewhat highfalutin.)
- second case: most people tend to drop certain consonants like t and d when they're flanked by other consonants. So in *don**t**you*, the t is flanked by n and y, so some people might drop the t altogether. Most people, however, glottalise the t and pronounce it something like [ˈdəʊnʔju].
- third case: most people tend to [assimilate](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/246241/106592) the t of *don't* with the following glide /j/ and pronounce it with [t͡ʃ] (which is considered informal).

Once again, all of them are correct pronunciations.