# Why is the <th> in "posthumous" pronounced as <ch> (/tʃ/)?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, phonology, assimilation-linguistics

I have always pronounced the **th** in "[posthumous](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/posthumous)" as if it was the "th" in *think* (/θ/), but when I searched itd it was actually the **ch** /tʃ/:

- UK: /ˈpɒs.**tʃ**ə.məs/
- US: /ˈpɑːs.**tʃ**ə.məs/

I found [a language log discussion](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=43032), but it has not explained it.

Comment: I always pronounce the first 7 letters like those of 'lost human', with the emphasis on the first syllable.

Comment: I think I pronounce /tj/, but I can see how it could be /tʃ/ for some speakers.  The "h" is silent.

Comment: @rjpond Texas here, and the h most definitely is not silent; there's unvoiced air while forming the "o" vowel.

Comment: I pronounce it as 'post - hummus' like after you eat some ground chickpea paste, seasoned with tahini (sesame paste), minced garlic, and extra virgin olive oil.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### TL;DR

The reason why the ⟨th⟩ in *posthumous* is pronounced  /t͡ʃ/ (*ch*) is the coalescence/[assimilation](/a/248446/106592)<sup>**1**</sup> of the *t* and the following *u*.

#### Explanation

'Posthumous' is made up of the prefix *post-* and *humous*. *Post* ends in a /t/ and the ⟨h⟩ in *humous* is silent so it starts with a *u* which is basically /juː/ (the same as the *u* in 'cue'). We could say that *humous* starts with a glide /j/.

- post + (h)umous

the letter *u* is /juː/:

- pos/t/ + /juː/mous

In fact, [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/posthumous) gives /ˈpɒs**tj**ʊməs/ for *posthumous* i.e. /t/ + /j/.

You might have noticed that when a /t/ comes before a /j/, there's a tendency to assimilate them to /t͡ʃ/ ('ch' as in *chip*). The /t/ is normally articulated at the alveolar ridge, but when it comes before a /j/ (which is articulated further back in the mouth—at the hard palate), it's usually pronounced /t͡ʃ/. What happens here is that the /t/ is articulated further back in the mouth in anticipation of the following /j/, so it becomes /t͡ʃ/ i.e. they coalesce/assimilate to a /t͡ʃ/:

- pos /t͡ʃuː/ mous

That's where the /t͡ʃ/ came from. The same goes for the *tu* in *nature* (na/t͡ʃ/re).

---

**1.** **[Assimilation](/a/270790/106592)** is a process that makes nearby sounds more similar to each other. The kind of assimilation in *posthumous* is called 'coalescent assimilation'. The following sounds often coalesce:

- /t/ and /j/ coalesce to /t͡ʃ/ (as in *posthumous*)
- /d/ and /j/ coalesce to /d͡ʒ/ (as in *e**du**cation*)
- /s/ and /j/ coalesce to /ʃ/ (*ble**ss y**ou* is sometimes pronounced *bleshoo*)
- /z/ and /j/ coalesce to /ʒ/ (as in *vi**sio**n*)

---

<sup>/t/ is the T in **t**ime

/j/ is the Y in **y**ou

/t͡ʃ/ is the CH in **ch**in

/d͡ʒ/ is the J in **j**oin

/ʃ/ is the SH in **sh**ip

/ʒ/ at the end of massa**ge**</sup>

Comment: Another relevant comparison for that *tu* assimilation is *posture*.

Comment: I think you get the same effect with “posthumanism”, where you'd usually expect the ‘h’ to be pronounced as [ç] rather than completely silent.

Comment: Same effect with _postulate_.

Comment: @Suncat2000: *Mature, prostitute, substitute, posture, institute, astute, tune etc. (at least in BrE)*

Comment: Just adding: _Tudor_.

Comment: In my US English dialect, only mature and posture assimilate like that. I'm not sure what the rule is.

Answer (score 12):

'Post' is a common prefix in English, from the Latin for 'last' which to us essentially means '*after*'.

The English 'posthumous' literally means *after burial*. For the full etymology of the word from Latin, see [this reference](https://www.etymonline.com/word/posthumous).

Some words that use this prefix are not compound words but hyphenated, for example, '*post-mortem*' (an examination *after* one's *death*).

So the reason why the 'th' are not pronounced together as in the word '*think*' is because they are in effect part of different words - the 't' is the end of the prefix and the 'h' is the beginning of the root word. A comparable example would be the word '*lighthouse*' - a compound of 'light' and 'house'.

However, the 'h' isn't really pronounced at all in 'posthumous'. There are plenty of other words where an 'h' following a 't' is not pronounced - such as *neanderthal*, *thyme*. These do seem to be exceptional though, as 'h' is pronounced more often than not. Etymology is very often the reason, and unfortunately, there is no 'rule' to guide you on how to pronounce 'th' in an unfamiliar word.

Comment: @rjpond it appears to have changed over time - I'm not getting into that as the definition isn't part of the question anyway, so I've removed that and added a link.

Comment: But *why* is the **th** pronounced /t͡ʃ/?

Comment: @Void the "th" isn't pronounced  /t͡ʃ/.  The "thu" is /tju:/ (the "h" is silent), which, due to yod-coalescence, can become /t͡ʃu:/.

Comment: @rjpond: I know! I'm in the middle of explaining it. But this answer doesn't explain that

Comment: @void I've added in some detail, hopefully, it will explain.

Comment: *neanderthal* and *thyme* are of course toponyms and those often withstand pronunciation rules

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I accept that neanderthal is a toponym, but ,,, thyme... really?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think that more importantly, it's not a natively English word.

Comment: It doesn't ***really*** mean after-burial. That’s just [a Roman folk etymology handed down to us from yesteryear](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56683748#56683748).

Comment: @tchrist It came to mean that in Latin before it became the root of the English word. It started out as the superlative of the word for 'late', but was changed to incorporate the word *humare* (to bury). When that change was made, it ceased to be a superlative, so without overcomplicating the answer, I think it is safe to say that is what the root of the English word meant.

Comment: Here I thought _posthumous_ meant after (post) being turned into dirt (humus). Live and learn.

Comment: @Acccumulation What makes something a “native English word” anyway? One written in runes by seventh-century Saxons like *wall* and *wine* and *mile*? :)